# Has anything been done on $x^2-y^2-z^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The representation of integers by the sums of three squares is a well studied problem. But, has anything been done on $x^2-y^2-z^2$?

Maybe I haven't looked hard enough - although I think I have. A reference or two would be appreciated rather than anyone spending serious time on this. Thank you.

Comment: Every number congruent to $0, 1, $ or $3$ modulo $4$ can be given as a difference of squares. So every integer can be expressed as $x^2-y^2-z^2$. Also, pretty sure this isn't representation theory.

Comment: Representation theory studies the actions of groups on vector spaces. The sort of 'representation' in the OP is unrelated.

Answer (score 3):

You [want *Modern Elementary Theory of Numbers* by Leonard Eugene Dickson.](http://oskicat.berkeley.edu/record=b14598495~S1) On page 161 we find Theorem 115. Dickson and his students Ross and Oppenheim found all indefinite ternary quadratic forms that are universal. There are four types. Letting $M$ be any nonzero integer and $N$ any odd integer, the forms are equivalent to one of these:
$$ xy - M z^2,  $$
$$  2xy - N z^2, $$
$$  2xy + y^2 - N z^2,  $$
$$  2xy + y^2 - 2N z^2.  $$

Alright, half the Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives of your form is
$$
H = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Half the Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives $2xy - z^2$ is
$$
G = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Taking integer matrix
$$
P = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
we find
$$  P^T H P = G.  $$
If we then take 
$$
Q = P^{-1} = 
\left(
\begin{array}{rrr}
1 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}
\right),
$$
we find
$$  Q^T G Q = H.  $$

Dickson also says the conditions on $ax^2 + b y^2 + c z^2$ to be universal; that is the way you worded your question. Put briefly, there must be integers $u,v,w,$ not all zero, with $au^2 + b v^2 + c w^2=0,$ as well as $abc$ being odd or twice an odd number.

Comment: Thank you. I have some homework!